# Restrict content on Youtube - embed in Wordpress?

Tags: youtube, embed

For a client, I am going to create a website which, like this one https://nicolewilkins.com/category/video/ , has video lessons on it - and the lessons are restricted to members of the site.

I would like to put my videos in Youtube and then embed them in the individual blog posts. But can I "hide" the Youtube account, on which I post the videos, so that people can't view the videos for free on Youtube?

Thanks :-)